Minimum value of $f(m) = m^2 + \frac2{m^2 + 2}+5$.
So with this question, I had to find the minimum value of $f(m) = m^2 + \frac{2}{m^2 + 2} + 5$.
So I first tried using the AM-GM Inequality simplifying the terms, adding $2$ to $m^2$ and subtracting it from $5$. When I applied it, the answer was $3 + 2\cdot2^{1/2}$.
But after solving using calculus I got $m = 0$ and the answer became $6$.
Can anyone please explain the reason behind this?

Welcome to MSE! Just remind that when you use AM-GM inequality, you’ve got to check if the values are positive, and just like the other inequalities, check if there is at least one value that satisfies the equality.

Can you show your work? You likely made an error, which would be the reason behind this.

I think what happened is the following:
Using the AM-GM approach (Arithmetic Mean is greater or equal to the Geometric Mean), one would rewrite $f(m)$ as
$$f(m) = (m^2 + 2) + \frac2{m^2+2} + 3$$
and then argue that by the AM-GM inequality (Arithmetic Mean is greater or equal to the Geometric Mean) we have
$$\frac{(m^2 + 2) + \frac2{m^2+2}}2 \ge \sqrt{(m^2 + 2) \times \frac2{m^2+2}} = \sqrt{2}$$
That results in
$$f(m) \ge 2\sqrt{2} + 3.$$
I think you made a calculation error somewhere, because you have a different value added to $3$.
And that inequality isn't wrong, it's correct, despite the calculus result.
But nowhere does it mean that the minimum of $f(m)$ must be $2\sqrt{2} + 3$. To be able to say that, we need to verify that the case where the AM-GM inequality becomes an equality can be obtained.
That means we must verify that $(m^2 + 2) = \frac2{m^2+2}$ is possible, which is equivalent to $(m^2+2)^2 = 2$ and thus $m^2+2 = \pm \sqrt{2}$, which is impossible, because $m^2 +2 \ge 2$.
So while the AM-GM inequality got you a correct result, it didn't lead to the solution of the problem, because equality in it cannot be reached (which you failed to check).
Another way to look at the problem is to find the minumum of the function
$$g(x) = x + \frac2x + 3$$
in the interval $[2, \infty)$ (because those values are what $m^2+ 2$ can take).

That graph has been plotted above and you can see that it takes its minimum between $1.3$ and $1.5$ (the exact value, as we saw above, was $\sqrt{2}$) and is increasing from there on. That's why the real minimum of g(x) $[2, \infty)$ is at first possible value $x=2$ and that corresponds to the calculus resilt $m=0$.

The minimum of the function
$$g(x):=3+x+\frac2x\quad(\forall x>0)$$
is indeed $g(\sqrt2)=3+2\sqrt2$ (as you found using AM-GM inequality, and could as well be calculated directly from the computation of $g'$), but this is irrelevant.
Since $m^2+2\ge2$, what you are interested in is the minimum of the restriction of $g$ to $[2,\infty)$, namely $g(2)=6$.

I agree with your criticisms of my answer; my answer was very sloppy.  In a situation like this, rather than repair the answer, I think it best for me to simply delete the answer and leave the problem to another responder.
